# CASE WHEN with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this query,

```
SELECT T.A FROM T WHERE T.A IN (CASE WHEN T.B = 1 THEN (1,2,3) ELSE (4,5) END)
```

Is it possible or any alternative to this query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use case on where clause

```
SELECT T.A FROM T WHERE (T.A IN (1,2,3) And T.B = 1) or (T.A in (4,5) and T.B <>1)
```

Comment: You can use `CASE` in `WHERE`. The problem is that the `CASE` clause can have as a "result" a single value and not a composite one.

Comment: I said don't use case in where clause because And & or do many things  faster

Comment: Your query is not equivalent to the OP's. It will show a row with `A=4 and B=1` while the OP's one would not (if it worked).

Answer (score 3):

[`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is an *expression* - it returns a single result of a well defined type:

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.

For some complex `WHERE` clauses, it may make sense to use it (your current one can be solved without, as @Somebody is in trouble's answer shows), but you need to structure it to return a single result value or expression:

```
SELECT T.A FROM T WHERE
  1 = CASE
         WHEN T.B = 1 AND T.A IN (1,2,3) THEN 1
         WHEN T.A IN (4,5) THEN 1
      END
```

Comment: I don't think a a row with `A=4 and B=1` is wanted by the OP.

Comment: @ypercube - possibly so - but were the `CASE` expression to work as they seem to want it to, it would be in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T.A 
FROM T 
WHERE  T.B = 1      AND  T.A IN (1,2,3)  
   OR  T.B <> 1     AND  T.A IN (4,5) 
   OR  T.B IS NULL  AND  T.A IN (4,5) ;
```